# Can $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx_i^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx_i^n$ for distinct $(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ from interval $(0,1)$?

Tags: analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

Can we have an example of two distinct power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n$ with the radius of convergence equal $1$ and there exists a sequence $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $(-1,1)$ so that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx_i^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx_i^n$$
for $i\in \mathbb{N}$?

Theorem 8.5 in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* says we don't have such an example if $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a limit point in $(-1,1)$. What if $x_i\nearrow 1$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the power series of the following two functions around the origin
$$ f(z)= (1-z)^{-1} \cos( (1-z)^{-1}), g(z)=42 f(z).$$
The only singularity of $f,g$ is at $z=1$, hence the associated power series around the origin has radius of convergence equal to $1$. Furthermore, the functions are different, but have the same zeros, which accumulate at $z=1$, thus we get a counterexample.